# Call a method after statements have been evaluated

Tags: c#, methods, sharepoint-2010, optional-arguments

This should be very easy to answer but I'm not even sure how to ask it properly, so I apologize in advance for my n00b-ness. I have struggled to paraphrase it for searches with no luck...

Basically I have a method that takes several arguments as "switches" (set to 0 or 1 by the calling method) and optional strings and uses them to "build" its plan of action. It goes something like this:

```
public static void Foo(int a, int b, int c, optionalString aa, optionalString, bb, optionalString cc)
{
    if (a == 1)
    { Object1 o1 = Thing.Property1[aa]; }
    if (b == 1)
    { Object2 o2 = Thing.Property2[bb]; }
    if (c == 1)
    { Object3 o3 = Thing.Property3[cc]; }

    Bar(optionalo1, optionalo2, optionalo3); // Edit: I explained this part a little wrong, see below.
}
```

**Edit for clarification:** I cannot pass null values to `Bar()` because it needs to be called only with the properties that were actually set. For example, Foo() is invoked with a, b, and c set like this:

```
Foo(1, 0, 1, string1, string3) //In this instance I only want the first and third properties set. The strings contain the values I want them set to.
{
    if (a == 1)
    { set this property based on string1 }
    if (b == 1)
    { this one would not be set because b was 0 }
    if (c == 1)
    { set this property based on string3 }

    Bar(property1, property3);
    // In this instance, Bar() must be called with only those two arguments, it cannot contain any null values.
```

**End of edit**

So, without using a crapload of nested `if()` statements or methods for every possible combination of `Bar()`, is there a way to just call it once all those have been evaluated? Technically the variables haven't been assigned yet, so `Bar()` is not valid. Alternately, is there a better way to accomplish something like this?

This is for a console app that interacts with SharePoint server object model, if that makes any difference. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: first of all a "switch" that can either be 0 or 1 is not an int, its a `bool`.

Comment: also, those string parameters are not optional in the strict sense, why not just use `string aa == null` and if its null don't use it?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  It appears that except for some weird-o naming issues you have going on in your sample code, that it does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: post some relevant codes, i feel like alien when i see IFoo, Foo & Bar

Comment: can't you solve this with generics?

Comment: Outside of what HighCore said, I am not confident much can be said to help you given the lack of information.  Make it work, then make it right.  It appears to me that you are trying to optimize code that is not finished.

Comment: I cannot understand what you're trying to convey in this question. Variable names are too inconsistent... please consider reworking your example code to be more clear.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to give an example of "every possible combination of `Bar()`" please? I can only think of 4 combinations (`Bar()`, `Bar(arg1)`, `Bar(arg1, arg2)`, `Bar(arg1, arg2, arg3)` which can be resolved with the answer already given. (i.e. just call `Bar(arg1, arg2, arg3)` passing in null where the switch for the optional parameters is 0)

Comment: Please see the edit for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to convert your code into data. You have some input parameters and you need to perform some action on them.

Use a dictionary structure defined as `Dictionary<Key, Action>` where `Key = whatever unique value` you can create. Then all you have to do in your method is to calculate the key and execute the associated action.

From your example:

```
    public static void Foo(int a, int b, int c, optionalString aa, optionalString, bb, optionalString cc)
    {
Dictionary<int, Action> objectMapper = new Dictionary<int, Action>
        {
            { 0, () => Bar() },
            { 1, () => Bar(Thing.Property1[aa]) },
            { 2, () => Bar(Thing.Property2[bb]) },
            { 4, () => Bar(Thing.Property3[cc]) },
            { 3, () => Bar(Thing.Property1[aa], Thing.Property2[bb]) },
            { 5, () => Bar(Thing.Property1[aa], Thing.Property3[cc]) },
            { 6, () => Bar(Thing.Property2[bb], Thing.Property3[cc]) },
            { 7, () => Bar(Thing.Property1[aa], Thing.Property2[bb], Thing.Property3[cc]) },
        };    
        objectMapper[a & b & c]();
    }
```

In my example the unique key is simply `ANDing` the 3 input variables. However, as you see, covering every possibility is pretty tedious, which is why I do not recommend doing exactly this way, but try and rework your Bar method to be more flexible on input parameters.

Comment: Ah, this looks like a cleaner way to accomplish what I'm going for if all else fails. Thanks for the alternative! Unfortunately the `Bar()` method actually represents a series of actions on various object indexes specific to SharePoint, but in this case it is called in the same fashion as a regular method and is not flexible. If it is not called with the exact number and combination of arguments, it bombs. I can't change the way it works without rewriting a bunch of the SharePoint assembly.

Comment: @thanby, the lambda expression can be any sequence of statements you desire. But if you only have one public API call then you don't really have much choice. If you like my approach, then it would be nice to recognize it. :)

Comment: So far it's the best contender for an answer! (I don't have the rep to up-vote yet otherwise I would)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just want to pass null as default values to the `Bar` method like following:

```
public static void Foo(int a, int b, int c, 
    optionalString aa, optionalString, bb, optionalString cc)
{
    Object1 o1 = null;
    Object1 o2 = null;
    Object1 o3 = null;
    if (a == 1)
    { o1 = Thing.Property1[aa]; }
    if (b == 1)
    { o2 = Thing.Property2[bb]; }
    if (c == 1)
    { o3 = Thing.Property3[cc]; }

    Bar(o1, o2, o3);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the call to Bar() cannot contain any null values. Please see my edit for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the signature of Bar, yes.

If bar is declared something like

```
public static void Bar(params string[] values) {
    foreach(var v in values) {
        // use value
    }
}
```

Then Foo can just build an array and send it through, e.g.

```
var list values = new List<string>();

if(a == 1) {
    list.Add(optionalo1);
    // do whatever else
}

if(b == 1) {
    list.Add(optionalo2);
    // do whatever else
}

Bar(values.ToArray());
```

**Edit:**

Also bear in mind that if Foo is declared as

```
public static void Foo(int a, int b, int c, string aa = null, string bb = null, string cc = null)
```

and you call it like you did in your example with:

```
Foo(1, 0, 1, string1, string3)
```

then string1 will wind up in string1 as you intend, but the passed string3 will wind up in string2. You'll need to pass a null in that position into Foo or the values will be mixed up.

Comment: The call to `Foo()` specifies the arguments, like `(string1: firstString, string3: thirdString)` ...I did that right, didn't I? Like I said, I'm new to the language. `Bar()` cannot take arrays, but maybe I could build the call to it using an array to express the combination of arguments? (if that makes sense)

Comment: Yes, if you're naming the arguments to Foo, you'll be fine. I'm not sure how familiar you are with C#, so I apologise if I'm explaining something you already know, but declaring Bar like that doesn't restrict it to only receiving arrays. It will accept both arrays and individually passed values, i.e. you can still call it with a list of arguments. You can find info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx. If what you're trying to do involves a variable number of parameters none of which can be null, I think you'll need to use params.

Comment: From reading that msdn article it looks like params may be one solution to my problem. I'll try it out to see what works best. Thanks for the advice!